# Fuel UI Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, gulp, fuelux

I am trying to use a Fuel UI Spinner in a project that uses Bower for dependency management and gulp.js for builinding files.

Here is my code:

**gulpfile.js:**

```
...
 gulp.task('js', function() {
     gulp
        .src([
            'bower_components/jquery/jquery.js',
            ...
            ...
            'bower_components/fuelux/dist/loader.min.js',
            'bower_components/fuelux/dist/spinner.js',
            'js/script.js'
            ])
            ...
        ...
    ...
...
```

**script.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    ...
    $(".qty-spinner").spinner();
    ...

}
```

When I do this I get the following error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using bootstrap 3 and fuelux is not currently compatible with BS3, so this look like a candidate for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you are missing some lib, I guess RequireJS?
I see that Fuel UX uses RequireJS

https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux#amd

Comment: Trying to avoid AMD if posisble as I am using Gulp.  You can see that I have added the loader.min.js which should work without Require.

Comment: But define shouldn't be used by anyone else, right? 
Try to see the line you get the error and go from there.